# Uploading .xlsx file and processing it with .py file when we click submit button and store data to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am developing program where I can upload excel invoice .xlsx file using Flask and then store that file to mysql when user click submit button. There are total three files involved. getFile.py which is Flask to upload file using index.html. exlTomySQL.py store data to mysql from file received by index.html. I am new to Flask and don't know how to process data after clicking submit button on index.html to process .xlsx file and return response for user.

**getFile.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        fileDetails = request.form
        myFile = fileDetails['myfile']

        return myFile

    return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**exlToSQL.py**

```
import openpyxl
import math
import datetime
import mysql.connector

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('myFile')
sheet = wb.active

# count rows of data for column 2 as it represent description


def countRows():
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, 100, 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value != None:
            count = i
    return count


# list each row description, (not counting quantity), gst amount and last column(total excluding GST)


def readRows():
    description = []
    # quantity = []
    amount = []
    gstAmount = []

    for i in range(3, countRows() + 1, 1):
        description.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
        # quantity.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value)
        gstAmount.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value)
        amount.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value)
    uperCaseDescription = [desc.upper()
                           for desc in description]
    return uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount

# count all list totals for GST and Amount


def countTotals():
    uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount = readRows()

    totalGST = round(sum(gstAmount), 2)
    subTotalAmount = round(sum(amount), 2)
    totalAmountOfInvoice = round((totalGST + subTotalAmount), 2)

    return totalGST, subTotalAmount, totalAmountOfInvoice


# get static data of invoice e.g. invoice number,
# invoice date, sub total, total gst, total inc gst

print(countRows())
print(countTotals())
invoice_number = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value
print("Invoice Number:", invoice_number)
invoice_date = sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value
print("Invoice Date:", invoice_date)

sun_offset = (invoice_date.weekday() - 6) % 7

weekEnd = invoice_date - datetime.timedelta(days=sun_offset)
print("Week End Date:", weekEnd)

print(readRows())

# merge all list into tuple


def mergeList():
    uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount = readRows()

    mergeTuple = tuple(zip(uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount))
    return mergeTuple


# MySql connection and transfer data to mysql


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="Vrishab2145",
    database="testdbOne"
)
# creating database_cursor to perform SQL operation

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO invoice (description, gstAmount, totalExGst) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, mergeList())
mydb.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the file being uploaded by making some changes in your code as shown below.

Once you have saved the file, you can deal with the file processing to store the data to MySQL. You can also delete the file previously saved once the processing is done.

**getFile.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["UPLOADS"] = "C:/FlaskSandbox/uploads" # path where uploads are saved. Can also be UNIX path


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userfile = request.files['myfile']
        userfile.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOADS"], userfile.filename))
        print('File Saved!')

        # call your file processing functions below

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ''''openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
'''

Comment: Getting above error looks like file object is not recognise xlsx object, can you help plz

Comment: I can upload file to UPLOADS folder however, not able to read it. getting bellow error. `FileNotFoundError
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'invoice.xlsx'`

Answer (score 0):

Bellow Code working perfectly fine. After spending so many days finally worked out.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import openpyxl
import math
import datetime
import mysql.connector


app = Flask(__name__)
# path where uploads are saved. Can also be UNIX path
app.config["UPLOADS"] = "/Users/vrishabpatel/Desktop/PythonPrep/FlaskApp/uploads"


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Vrishab2145",
        database="testdbOne"
    )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userfile = request.files['myfile']
        userfile.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOADS"], userfile.filename))
        print('File Saved!')

        # call your file processing functions below

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(userfile)

        sheet = wb.active

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO invoice (description, gstAmount, totalExGst) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, mergeList(sheet))
        mycursor.close()
        mydb.commit()

    return render_template('index.html')


# creating database_cursor to perform SQL operation
# countRows()
# readRows()
# countTotals()


def countRows(sheet):

    count = 0
    for i in range(1, 100, 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value != None:
            count = i
    return count


def readRows(sheet):

    description = []
    # quantity = []
    amount = []
    gstAmount = []

    for i in range(3, countRows(sheet) + 1, 1):
        description.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value)
        # quantity.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value)
        gstAmount.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=10).value)
        amount.append(sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value)
    uperCaseDescription = [desc.upper()
                           for desc in description]
    return uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount


def countTotals(sheet):

    uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount = readRows(sheet)

    totalGST = round(sum(gstAmount), 2)
    subTotalAmount = round(sum(amount), 2)
    totalAmountOfInvoice = round((totalGST + subTotalAmount), 2)

    return totalGST, subTotalAmount, totalAmountOfInvoice


def mergeList(sheet):

    uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount = readRows(sheet)

    mergeTuple = tuple(zip(uperCaseDescription, gstAmount, amount))
    return mergeTuple


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```